# position text on top of svg

Tags: svg, bootstrap-4

I am trying to move the "s" to where the grey box is. I tried doing it in css but that ruined the responsiveness

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="justify-content-center d-flex">
  <div class="container position-absolute h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 600" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect width="600" height="600" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <h1 class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">s</h1>
  </div>
</section>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raj2f.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `svg` to display at any size set and to be responsive, then you need to set the `h1` parent `div` class `.position-absolute` to overlay your `svg`, which has a parent `div` class set to `.position-relative`.

See example code below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="py-3">
  <div class="container">
  
    <div class="position-relative">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <rect width="600" height="600" fill="#C4C4C4"/>
      </svg>
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center position-absolute w-100 h-100 p-3" style="top:0;left:0;">
        <h1>S</h1>
      </div>  
    </div>
 
  </div>
</section>
```

There are other options like using the `svg` as a background image, or using `css` to position the text centrally over the `svg`. Lots of ways it could be done.

However using bootstrap 4 flex utilities, my code above is how I would approach this for being responsive to the `svg` native `viewBox` ratio.